# Declare one class variable via another

Tags: php, oop, class, php4

sorry for the vague title... I have a problem with a php4 class that seems hard to put to words.

My class has a "possibleValues" array, that holds information on what kind of values are acceptable for certain attributes that can be changed from the outside. In my pseudocode example below you can see that I have attributes that share the same acceptable values (colors). Obviously, the `$this->colors` in my code fails, because you can't define one class variable via another (can you?).

How would I go about setting a common colors array that I could reference like this so I don't have to repeat the same valid options for different fields that allow the same values?

```
Class MyTest {

    var $colors = array('red', 'yellow', 'blue');

    var $possibleValues = array(
        'someAttribute',               array(0,1),
        'someEmotions',                array('happy, 'sad'),
-->     'someColorableAttribute',      $this->colors,
-->     'someOtherColorableAttribute', $this->colors,
     );

    ...

}
```

Comment: I know, but that doesn't change the reality I am faced with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, you should set the variable in the constructor. In PHP4, which you really shouldn't be using, the constructor should have the name of the class.

```
function MyTest()
{
   $this->var = $this->colors;
}
```

Comment: That would work, yes. Is there a different way to do it in php5? I feel my idea of referencing one class variable to another is the real problem, not what version I am using. Is there other approaches to this problem? Is there a difference to class constants, for example, in php5?

Comment: Well, honestly; the standard would be to use a constructor (:

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set the `$possibleValues` in constructor, you can try this approach:

**PHP 4**

```
class MyTest {
    var $colors = array('red', 'yellow', 'blue');

    var $possibleValues = array(
        'someAttribute' =>             array(0,1),
        'someEmotions'  =>             array('happy', 'sad'),
        'someColorableAttribute' =>    'colors',
        'someOtherColorableAttribute' => 'colors',
     );


    function getPossibleValues($attr) {
        //no attribute, empty list
        if (!array_key_exists($attr, $this->possibleValues))
            return array();

        $possible_values = $this->possibleValues[$attr];
        //value is a string, check for object variable with such name
        if (is_string($possible_values)) {
            if (!array_key_exists($possible_values, get_object_vars($this)))
                return array();

            return $this->$possible_values;
        }

        return $possible_values;
    }
}

$a = new MyTest();
var_dump($a->getPossibleValues('someAttribute'));
var_dump($a->getPossibleValues('someEmotions'));
var_dump($a->getPossibleValues('someColorableAttribute'));
var_dump($a->getPossibleValues('someOtherColorableAttribute'));
```

I'm using `get_object_vars` since `property_exists` don't exist in PHP 4.

**PHP 5 (class constant)**

```
class MyTest {
    const COLORS = 'red|yellow|blue';

    private $possibleValues = array(
        'someAttribute' =>             array(0,1),
        'someEmotions'  =>             array('happy', 'sad'),
        'someColorableAttribute' =>    self::COLORS,
        'someOtherColorableAttribute' => self::COLORS,
     );


    public function getPossibleValues($attr) {
        //no attribute, empty list
        if (!array_key_exists($attr, $this->possibleValues))
            return array();

        $possible_values = $this->possibleValues[$attr];
        //value is a string, explode it around |
        if (is_string($possible_values)) {
            return explode('|', $possible_values);
        }

        return $possible_values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so basically I use a stand-in string to access a class variable of same name? I suppose this works, but it certainly feels like a big work around.

Comment: @kontur The standard would be to use constructor or repeat yourself (both PHP 4 and 5). I've updated the answer with PHP 5 example using class constant.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update. I've just seen other examples combining `define` and `serialize` for having an "constant array"/"class variable" array - interesting. Good to know my options in php5 also. Really appreciate your effort in explaining - @Lusitanian's answer seems to fit my problem better, but your's definately taught me more ;)